# Read file line-by-line or store in memory?

Tags: python, file, ram

This is less of a "my code's broken" question and more of a "should I do this?" question.

I have a script that iterates line-by-line using somethting like this: `reader = csv.DictReader(open('file.txt', 'rb'), delimiter= '\t')` and gets things like ages and dates *without committing the whole thing to memory.*

As it stands, the script [uses about 5% of my RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89ZE3.png) (8GB).

In general, is it more accepted to put a file into memory instead of opening it and looping through its contents -- especially if it's large (over 700MB)?

My script is for personal use, but I'd rather learn Python's conventions and do what's considered acceptable. For example, I know that if I were doing something similar in JavaScript I'd try to conserve memory as much as possible to prevent browsers from crashing or becoming unresponsive.

Is a method (memory vs looping) preferred over another in Python?

edit: I'm aware this could be kind of broad. I'm more curious as to the best (Pythonic) practice.

There seems to be a lot of posts asking *how* to do it, but not a lot asking *why* or *if*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, your method is the pythonic way to do this.

You should be aware of the fact that `open('file.txt')` does not put the whole file into memory. It returns an iterator which reads the file on demand. So does your `DictReader`.

Just try processing a large file, you won't see any increase in memory consumption.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm using it. Is there any benefit to loading it to memory opposed to the method I'm using?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do with the values. This way you can only read the values sequentially, i.e. if you got the 10th value, you cannot go back to the first one unless you reopen the file. So if you intend to jump back and forth, you might want to save the values in a list like `[d for d in DictReader(...)]`

Comment: Ahh, okay. I'm getting all specific values, so back and forth doesn't matter. So in this case it'd probably be better to use less memory. But would I be correct in assuming that having it loaded into RAM + having it be an object (or whatever it's called in Python) would result in a faster lookup?

Comment: @eric_lagergren: I think that reading line by line could also be faster. Or at least not much slower. But if you really want an answer you should try the two solutions and measure them.

Comment: Getting back to your original question "should i do this":
The pythonic way is to write your code as concise as possible. You should not care about which way is faster or uses less resources unless you really get a resource problem. Therefore the answer is: You should do it this way unless you got some good reasons not to.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, it's better to process the file as you read it. The operating system expects such behaviour so it reads ahead a bit to compensate for the latency of the disk system. Loading the file in its entirety will normally reserve the memory used for only your process which is wasteful if you're only scanning through it once. You could mmap it, which lets the system use disk buffers directly, but that loses the hint of where you will be reading next. Reading too small chunks causes the system call overhead to dominate so you'll want to read fairly large chunks if possible, but for most programs the default buffering while reading lines is sufficient.